# What are some Group representation of the rubik's cube group?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, rubiks-cube

The [Rubik's cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_Cube_group) corresponds to valid sequences of moves of the Rubik's cube. What are some [group representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_finite_groups) of this group (with respect to finite dimensional vector spaces on finite fields)?

Ideally, I am looking for embeddings. I know that you can make a representation of the symmetric group 48 on a 48 dimensional vector space, and then embed the rubik's cube group into that. Can you make a representation based on a lower dimensional vector space?

(My group theory and linear algebra are a little rusty. Feel free to edit this to make more sense.)

Comment: It's easy enough to get down to dimension $20$ over, say, $\mathbb F_7$, by encoding the permutation of the $12+8$ movable cubies like a permutation matrix, except encoding the _orientation_ change of each cubie by a nonzero factor -- $-1$ instead of $1$ for a flip of an edge, $2$ for a right-hand twist of a corner, for example.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Why $\mathbb F_7$ in particular?

Comment: x @PyRulez: That is the smallest field that contains both an element of multiplicative order 2 (which I need to encode edge flips) and one of multiplicative order 3 (which I need to encode corner twists).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think $20$ is the smallest degree of a faithful representation of the Rubik cube group, certainly in characteristic $0$ or characteristic coprime to the group order, and probably over any field. As Henning Makholm commented, there exist faithful representations of degree $20$, so we just need to show that this is the smallest degree possible.

The Rubik cube group contains a subgroup $H = H_1 \times H_2$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ have the structures $H_1 = 2^{11}:A_{12}$ and $H_2 =3^7:A_8$.

Now the only nontrivial proper normal subgroups of $H_1$ are its centre $M$ of order $2$, and an elementary abelian group $N$ of order $2^{11}$. In particular, $M$ is its unique minimal normal subgroup, so a minimal degree faithful representation of $H_1$ must be irreducible. Its restriction to $N$ cannot be homogeneous (since $N$ is abelian but not cyclic), and its homogeneous components are permuted by $A_{12}$, so there must be at least $12$ of them.

So the smallest degree of a faithful representation of $H_1$ is $12$ and similarly it is $8$ for $H_2$. By the theory of representations of direct products, the smallest degree of a faithful irreducible representation of $H$ is $12 \times 8 = 96$. Since $H$ has exactly two minimal normal subgroups, the only way we could improve on that is with a representation with two constituents having different minimal normal subgroups in their kernels, and doing that results in a faithful representation of degree (at least) $20$.

Comment: Can you explain the notation $2^{11}:A_{12}$ and which subgroups it is you call $H$, $H_1$ and $H_2$?

Comment: This is ATLAS notation.  $2^{11}:A_{12}$ denotes a group $G$ with a normal elementary abelian subgroup $N$ of order $2^{11}$ such that $G/N \cong A_{12}$. The $:$ indicates that the extension is split i.e. $N$ has a complement in $G$. The Rubik cube group is a subgroup of index $12$ in a group $(2^{12}:A_{12}) \times (3^8:A_8),$ with the permutation actions of $A_{12}$ and $A_8$ on the normal elementary abelian subgroups.

Comment: Can you describe these groups them in terms of the cube? In particular it seems to me that $(2^{12}:A_{12})\times(3^8:A_8)$ would have too few elements for the Rubik group to have index 12 in it. Did you mean $(2^{12}:S_{12})\times(3^8:S_8)$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant $(2^{12} : S_{12}) \times (3^8 : S_8)$.

Comment: Okay, and your $H_1$ and $H_2$ are then the kernels of the projection maps from this product, restricted to the Rubik group?

Comment: Yes that's right. $H_1 \times H_2$ has index $2$ in the Rubik cube.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I haven't checked through your whole argument yet, but here's one concern:  $H_1$ has a center of order 2, generated by flipping all 12 edges (i.e. the superflip).  Your $N$ only becomes minimal normal after modding out by the center.

Comment: @RaviFernando Yes you are right! I have attempted to correct the argument.

Comment: @DerekHolt Wonderful, I think I understand the argument now.  Thanks for your answer.